# Velocity normal to surface in thermionic emission

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

In the derivation of the Richard-Dushman law which relates the current density $J$ from thermionic emission in a filament of temperature $T$ and work function $\phi$

$$J = AT^2e^{-\frac{\phi}{kT}}$$

we get this expression by integrating over all electrons in the occupied energy states

$$J = \int N(E)v_x(E)dE $$

where the integration is carried over limits discussed below and x is the direction normal to the surface of the metal. $N(E)$ is the number density of electrons with energy in the range $E$ to $E + dE$. $N(E) = f(E)g(E)$ where $f(E)$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution. A derivation of this is given [here](http://mafija.fmf.uni-lj.si/seminar/files/2007_2008/Thermionic_emission.pdf). I have two questions:

1. To relate $v_x(E)$ with $E$ the relation $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is used. Why is this valid? $E$ is just the energy of the quantum state the electron occupies. How is it related to its kinetic energy?
2. It is claimed that for the electron to escape it must have atleast $\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2 \geq E_F + \phi$, where $E_F$ is the Fermi energy. Why is this true? For electrons sitting in higher quantum states shouldn't the minimum velocity required be lesser that this? Shouldn't it be $1/2mv_x^2 + E \geq E_F + \phi$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think EF is Fermi level, the concept of Fermi energy applies only to absolute zero temperature. Fermi level is energy of a quantum state with 50% probability of being fully occupied. At temperature > 0K the electrons have both: lower and higher energies. The ones with lower energies are much less likely to be excited enough to cross the metal-vacuum barrier. The ones with higher energy are more likely and are taken into account when integrating the Fermi-Dirac distribution.
Where I have problem to understand is that the liberated electrons have kinetic energies of at least work function, ie. difference between EF and vacuum state. But EF itself is not zero, so should not they have higher kinetic energies?